# what does '&' mean when used in a vim regex?

Tags: vim

What does '&' character mean when used in a vim regex like so:

```
:s/pattern/&nbsp;&nbsp;/g
```

Comment: Did you just ask a question to yourself publicly?

Comment: @romainl Have you read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/? Basically, if have a question and you find an answer and it isn't on SO, you're supposed to add it so that this can be the place on the internet with canonical answers. It's encouraged!

Comment: You can even make a question so long as you have something valuable to say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in a find and replace command '&' refers to what was found in the document. It is a way of reprinting whatever you looked up.

This:

```
:s/pattern/&nbsp;&nbsp;/g
```

would thus return:

```
patternnbsp;patternnbsp;
```

You can escape it like any other VIM metacharacter:

```
:s/pattern/\&nbsp;\&nbsp;/g
```

You can find more information here on Backreferences: http://vimregex.com/#backreferences

FYI: `&nbsp;` refers to a non-breaking space in HTML

Comment: Since & is meta-character in vim, you'll want to escape it in your pattern.

Comment: @DWright Nope, in *pattern* you don’t want to escape it because there it will have special meaning only when escaped (or in very-magic mode). You escape it only in *replacement*.